# error that the header can not be reset

Tags: node.js

I have a main file called server.js in which it has a method in post to call the request of url

```
var goToOther = require('./goToOther.js');

app.post ('/goToOther/', function (req, res) {
var data = {
    "Error": 1,
    "Zone" ""
};
    sms.goToOther (req, res, msgsms;

});
```

I have another file that is called the goToOther goToOther.js

exports.goToO

```
therUrl = function (req, res, next, msgsms) {
    var data = {
        "Error": 1,
        "Sms": ""
    };

var url = "http://www.google.com.br";


req.redirect ({
    uri: url,
    method: "POST"
}, Function (error, response, body) {
    console.log (error);
    //console.log(body);
    date ["error"] = 0;
    date ["sms"] = "successfully sent";
    res.json (data);
    next ();

});

};
```

I read some texts about it and did not understand what is happening and remade several times what I read between them I tried to recreate a new post method that sends calls the url but continued giving the error that the header can not be reset. The error is basically this: Error: Can not set after headers They are sent.

```
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader 
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Comment: Is `envioSMS` middleware? Where is the `next` param if it is?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be caused by just the code you have provided, there's something farther up the chain that is the root of this problem.

Comment: How i din't know for what is next used for i dind't use that.    thanks now i will add this in all functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In goToOther.js you need do this:
    You need create other variable to creat the request.
    So this is what i did and worked.

```
var request = require('request');
exports.envioSMS = function (req, res) {

    var url = "http://www.google.com";

    request ({
        uri: url,
        method: "POST"
    }, function (error, response, body) {
};
```